# Error when uploading a big image with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try to upload big images (>~1.5MB) to my website using PHP but the file dont appear on the server. Sometimes I get Error 1 (Max size exceeded).

Is there anything I can do?

```
public function do_upload($field) {
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['max_size'] = '100000';
    $config['max_width'] = '1024';
    $config['max_height'] = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload($field)) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        return $error;
    } else {
        /*$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        return $data;*/
        $updata =$this->upload->data();
        $data = $updata['raw_name'].$updata['file_ext'];
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Here can I call the function:

```
$pic = $this->do_upload('inputUpProfile');
```

Here I save the picture to the database:

```
        if ($this->input->post('post') == ''){
            $type="image";
        } else {
            $type="image-with-text";
        }
    } else {
        $pic = ""; 
        $type = "text"; 
    }

    $result = $this->blog->addPost($_SESSION['user_id'], $type  , $this->input->post('post'),$pic);
}
```

Models:

```
function addPost($user_id, $post_type, $post , $pic ) {
    $today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $vales = array('ev_user_id' => $user_id, 'ev_type' => $post_type, 'ev_text' => $post,'ev_pic' => $pic, 'ev_date' => $today);
    $this->db->insert($this->table_name, $vales);
}
```

The error:

> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'
>
> INSERT INTO `events` (`ev_user_id`, `ev_type`, `ev_text`, `ev_pic`,
>   `ev_date`) VALUES (1, 'image', '', Array, '2013-10-02 23:32:50')

Comment: can you try 'ev_pic' => $pic[0] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error speaks for itself: the fourth value (`Array`) is wrong. I suppose you want to store the filename in the database.

According to the [CodeIgniter documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) your `$pic` variable has a method `data()` that returns an array with the following fields:

```
Array
(
    [file_name]    => mypic.jpg
    [file_type]    => image/jpeg
    [file_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/
    [full_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/jpg.jpg
    [raw_name]     => mypic
    [orig_name]    => mypic.jpg
    [client_name]  => mypic.jpg
    [file_ext]     => .jpg
    [file_size]    => 22.2
    [is_image]     => 1
    [image_width]  => 800
    [image_height] => 600
    [image_type]   => jpeg
    [image_size_str] => width="800" height="200"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with the $pic definition, it has two definitions.

Change this:

```
function addPost($user_id, $post_type, $post , $pic ) {
    $today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $vales = array('ev_user_id' => $user_id, 'ev_type' => $post_type, 'ev_text' => $post,'ev_pic' => $pic, 'ev_date' => $today);
    $this->db->insert($this->table_name, $vales);
}
```

To this:

```
function addPost($user_id, $post_type, $post , $ev_pic ) {
    $today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $vales = array('ev_user_id' => $user_id, 'ev_type' => $post_type, 'ev_text' => $post,'ev_pic' => $ev_pic, 'ev_date' => $today);
    $this->db->insert($this->table_name, $vales);
}
```

Notice the **$pic** to **$ev_pic** change.

The error is with using the result from this call as the pic value in database:

```
$pic = $this->do_upload('inputUpProfile');
```